# Neo4j driver - confirm transaction success

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4j-python-driver

I have just started playing with the new neo4j driver for python and got totally stuck with transactions. How do I check if a transaction completed successfully? As far as I can say `commit` function does not automatically raise any errors, i.e. if for instance I provide it with an incorrect Cypher query I get no information on this.

I tried reading the `last_result` argument from the `Session` object and came up with sth like:

```
import neo4j.v1 as neo

def db_confirm_transaction_success(session):
    try:
        w = list(session.last_result)
        return True
    except neo.CypherError as e:
        session.last_result._consumed = True
        return False
    except neo.ResultError as e:
        session.last_result._consumed = True
        return False
```

It kind a works... Yet, it does require modifying private attributes and simply do not seem right/correct. There must be a simpler and more elegant solution.

Thank you in advance for help.

**Edit**: Just to make it clear `Transaction.success` attribute indicates if a  transaction should get committed or rolled back. Yet, e.g. Cypher errors can be identified as late as of the queries' execution time.

Answer (score 6):

I was banging my head on the same thing until I gave the [developer manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/pdf/neo4j-developer-manual-3.0-python.pdf) a read.

Up until then, I couldn't figure out why running several bad statements with `session.run(statement)` would not raise an exception, but rather, `session.close()` would.

Then i tried using something like:

```
with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
    tx.run(statement)
    tx.success = True
```

If you don't want the context manager, you can use:

```
tx = session.begin_transaction()
tx.run(statement)
tx.commit()
```

If you read the [python docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/_modules/neo4j/v1/session.html#Session.run) you might notice `tx.commit()` is the same thing as running `tx.success=True` and `tx.close()`.

The problem with this, is that calling `commit()` only appends a `COMMIT` cypher message to the connection's stream. To my knowledge it does not verify the success of the transaction.

---

After reading section 18 in the manual, I found that because I was not explicitly consuming the results, there was no guarentee that the statement was processed because the library using lazy loading (retreival of results only on demand). See the note from 18.1 below:

"Result records are loaded lazily as the cursor is moved through the stream. This
means that the cursor must be moved to the first result before this result can be
consumed. It also means that the entire stream must be explicitly consumed before
summary information and metadata is available. It is generally best practice to
explicitly consume results and close sessions, in particular when running update
statements. This applies even if the summary information is not required. Failing to
consume a result can lead to unpredictable behaviour as there will be no guarantee
that the server has seen and handled the Cypher statement."

---

So, essentially, you need to explicitly consume your results after running a cypher statement. This can be done like this:

```
res = session.run(statement) # or the equivalent iusing transaction style
res.consume()
```

I noticed the `.consume()` function calls `list(self)` to iterate over all the results (The StatementResult class defines an `__iter__` method). So, while I haven't tested it, it might be the case that simply looping over the results does the consumption for you:

```
res = session.run(statement)
for r in res:
    continue
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post an updated answer for `Neo4j 4.x`.

```
def commit_data(query):
    with driver.session(database="neo4j") as session:
        tx = session.begin_transaction()
        result = tx.run(query)
        result = [dict(i) for i in result]
        
       # uncomment below line to see the complete txn summary.
        # print(result) 

        if result[0]['failedOperations']>0:
            print(query)
            print(result)
            raise 'Error! Please recheck your query.'
        
        tx.commit()
```

Hope it will help others.